# NetIQ eDirectory LDAP nested groups

Tags: java, edirectory, netiq

I'm experimenting the `nestedGroupAux` class of the eDirectory. It works fine to return all the members of a group as well as those of the nested groups, but is it possible to distinguish between direct members of the group and members obtained by inference, and that are actually members of some nested group?